# How can I not record 0 in the final result

Tags: java, methods

I am doing a method exercise is about input some value which is more than -50000 and less than 50000 and when user input 0 the program is stop and caculate some result. My issue is when I input all postive number and also input 0 to exit, the program will save the 0 number and show to my smallest number in my final result, which mean is when I input 1,2,3,4,0 the smallest number should be 1 not 0, because 0 it is for exit the program. I think I know the issue is in for loop the smallest is save the input value, but I just do not know how to fix this issue to separate the input number and exit number.

```
package exercise;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class array {
    static final Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    
    System.out.println("Input some numbers , press 0 to exit");
    check();
    
}
    
    public static void check() {
        int pos=0;
        int neg=0;
        double topos=0;
        double toneg=0;
        double lar=0;
        double sma=0;
        double in;
        
        do {
            in = input.nextDouble();
            
            if(in>0 && in <50000) {
                pos++;
                topos=topos+in;
                
            }else if(in <0 && in>-50000) {
                neg++;
                toneg+=in;
            }
            for(double i=0;i<pos+neg;i++) {
                if(in>lar) {
                    lar=in;
                }
                if(in<sma &&in !=0) {
                    sma=in;
                }
                
            }
            }while(in !=0);
        
            
            System.out.println(neg+pos+" numbers input");
            System.out.println("Total pos "+topos);
            System.out.println("Total neg "+toneg);
            System.out.println("Aver pos "+topos/pos);
            System.out.println("Ave neg "+toneg/neg);
            System.out.println("Ave all "+(topos+toneg)/(pos+neg));
            System.out.println("Largest number "+lar);
            System.out.println("Smallest number "+sma);
                        
    }
        
}
```

Comment: you initialize `sma` with 0 and check if `in < sma`. therefore the condition is only true for negative numbers and `sma` will never change for positive numbers.

Comment: thanks for you advices @sinclair, I change the initalize it is work

Comment: Besides, there is no need for the `for`-loop at all, you sound never use floating-point variables as a counter.

Comment: @sinclair year, you are right, I also delete the for loop, it still work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @sinclair points out in the comments, you are initializing `sma` in 0, so the only numbers that can replace `sma`'s value are negatives. To fix it, initialize `sma` in the greatest value your program should recognize. That way, every number that is not 0 will be properly used in the comparison and repalce `sma`'s value if needed.

Change `sma=0;` for `sma=50000;`

I use 50000 as the greatest value you check for is 49999, and if that's is the only number the user inputs, then it is the smallest.

Comment: thanks for you advice @Jetto Martinez, I change the initialize value it is work

Answer (score 0):

Try to use meaningful Identifier names also as added by @sinclair you need to initialize the first element as smallest and largest that can be a possible solution.

```
public static void check() {
    int pos=0;
    int neg=0;
    double topos=0;
    double toneg=0;
    double lar;
    double sma;
    double in;
    in = input.nextDouble();
    sma = in;
    lar = in;
    do {
          if(in>0 && in <50000) {
              pos++;
              topos=topos+in;
            
          }else if(in <0 && in>-50000) {
              neg++;
              toneg+=in;
          }
          if(in>lar) {
              lar=in;
          }
          if(in<sma && in!=0) {
              sma=in;
          }
          in = input.nextDouble();
        }while(in !=0);
    
        System.out.println(neg+pos+" numbers input");
        System.out.println("Total pos "+topos);
        System.out.println("Total neg "+toneg);
        System.out.println("Aver pos "+topos/pos);
        System.out.println("Ave neg "+toneg/neg);
        System.out.println("Ave all "+(topos+toneg)/(pos+neg));
        System.out.println("Largest number "+lar);
        System.out.println("Smallest number "+sma);
                    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to propose you separate reading values from input and processing into two separated methods. The advantage of this approach is that you separate the condition for the exit and the rest of the logic.

```
static final Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    var numbers = getNumbers();

    check(numbers);
}

private static List<Double> getNumbers() {
    System.out.println("Input some numbers , press 0 to exit");

    List<Double> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
    double number;

    while (true) {
        number = input.nextDouble();

        if (number == 0) {
            break;
        }

        numbers.add(number);
    }
    return numbers;
}

public static void check(List<Double> numbers) {
    System.out.println(numbers);

    int pos=0;
    int neg=0;
    // ... other values
    
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++) {
        double number = numbers.get(i);

        if (number > 0 && number < 50000) {
            pos++;
            topos = topos + in;
        }

        // ... other checks
    }

    System.out.println(neg + pos + " numbers input");
    System.out.println("Total pos " + topos);
    System.out.println("Total neg " + toneg);
    System.out.println("Aver pos " + topos / pos);
    System.out.println("Ave neg " + toneg / neg);
    System.out.println("Ave all " + (topos + toneg) / (pos + neg));
    System.out.println("Largest number " + lar);
    System.out.println("Smallest number " + sma);
}
```

Comment: thanks for you reply @djm.im, I did learn something about list before, I think it is out of my knowledge, I am try to understand you code, should I add some import code for the list?

Comment: With the approach that I describe you can split code into two parts. The first part is reading values and store them into a list (the method `getNumbers`). And the second part is you get numbers, one by one, from the list and then process them.

Comment: If you learned about arrays, you can treat lists as arrays with "dynamically length". That means you don't need to care about the size and storing elements into it. You just add and get values from the list. (This is a little bit simplify).

Comment: I hope this makes sense? Do you need more clarification? @Eren